# Changing the color of the elements in the navigation bar when visited

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I have the following navigation bar for my Website:

The whole Code is here [in plnkr](http://plnkr.co/edit/?p=preview)

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css">
<script src="script.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://www.w3schools.com/w3css/4/w3.css">  
</head>
<body>
<div class="scrollmenu w3-bar w3-border w3-card-4" id="myHeader">
<a style="float:left" href="index.html" class="w3-bar-item w3-mobile w3- 
border-right">Menu</a>
<a href="animationbasics1.html" class="w3-bar-item w3-mobile w3-border- 
right">Animation Basics1</a>    
<a href="animationbasics2.html" class="w3-bar-item w3-mobile w3-border- 
right">Animation Basics2</a>    
<a href="animationbasics3.html" class="w3-bar-item w3-mobile w3-border- 
right">Animation Basics3</a>    
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

I wrote this active function but it is not working in plnkr, so that the color of the active element would change to red, so the user knows where he is.

```
 $('a').each(function(){
    if ($(this).prop('href') == window.location.href) {
        $(this).addClass('active');
        curpage = $(this).attr("title");
    }
  });
```

My Problem is, I want know to write a function, to change the color of an already visited element to light blue or something else, so the user knows that he already visited this page.

I am thankful for every suggestion or solution!

Cheers!

Comment: Already visited anytime ? or during the current session of the user ?

Comment: did you try pseudo class ":visited"

Comment: Already visited any time, so the changed color would be also saved.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As suggested by others, the `:visited` pseudo class does the job.

```
a:visited {
  color:red;
}
```

I have also added the `:hover`(blue) and `.active`(green) states.

Here's a working [example](http://plnkr.co/edit/BZlDmcLbDfbvcrXxR2rS?p=preview).

Note: it won't work in incognito mode.

Answer (score 1):

Why doing this  in jQuery ?

Could you use css ? like :

```
a:visited{
color: red;
}
```

Comment: This is weird, did you try with "!important" to ignore other rules ?